# Unable to partition ViewModelBase and ViewModel into different files

Tags: f#

I have a WPF project and am struggling to figure out how to have two separate files:

- ViewModelBase
- ViewModel

When I put the classes in their own file, I receive a compile error for the viewModel because the ViewModelBase cannot be found.

Also, I am using a WPF project. As a result, I am unable to move files within Solution Explorer up and down based on file dependencies.

The code is below:

```
module MVVM

open System.ComponentModel
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.Patterns

    type ViewModelBase () =
        let propertyChanged = 
            Event<PropertyChangedEventHandler,PropertyChangedEventArgs>()

        let getPropertyName = function 
            | PropertyGet(_,pi,_) -> pi.Name
            | _ -> invalidOp "Expecting property getter expression"

        interface INotifyPropertyChanged with
            [<CLIEvent>]
            member this.PropertyChanged = propertyChanged.Publish

        member private this.NotifyPropertyChanged propertyName = 
            propertyChanged.Trigger(this,PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))

        member this.NotifyPropertyChanged quotation = 
            quotation |> getPropertyName |> this.NotifyPropertyChanged


    type ViewModel() =
        inherit ViewModelBase()
        let mutable firstName = ""
        let mutable lastName = ""

        member this.FirstName
            with get() = firstName 
            and set(value) =
                firstName <- value
                base.NotifyPropertyChanged(<@ this.FirstName @>)

        member this.LastName
            with get() = lastName 
            and set(value) =
                lastName <- value
                base.NotifyPropertyChanged(<@ this.LastName @>)

        member this.GetFullName() = 
            sprintf "%s %s" (this.FirstName) (this.LastName)
```

Any ideas on how I can compile this simple WPF project with a class per file?

Comment: It's quite a good idea to keep your view models in a separate project to the views defined by your XAML.  That way you're actively enforcing a separation between view and view model.  If you keep the view models in a traditional F# project, you'll have no problems reordering the files as you would normally.

Comment: Okay. That makes since. Just wanted to do a quick and dirty hello world app.

Comment: Why does it being a WPF project prevent you from reordering the files?  If it has something to do with VS, you can always do it by manually editing the .proj file.